# Generate interactive API docs from Tornado web server code

Tags: documentation, swagger, tornado, swagger-ui, api-doc

I have a Tornado web server that exposes some endpoints in its API.
I want to be able to document my handlers (endpoints) *in-code*, including description, parameters, example, response structure, etc., and afterwards generate an **interactive** documentation that enables one to "play" with my API, easily make requests and experience the response on a sandbox environment.

I know [Swagger](http://swagger.io/), and particularly their SwaggerUI solution is one of the best tools for that, but I get confused how it works. I understand that I need to feed the SwaggerUI engine some `.yaml` that defines my API, but how do I generate it from my code?
Many github libraries I found aren't good enough or only support Flask...

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To my understanding, SwaggerUI is dependent on swagger specification. 
So, it boils down to generating the Swagger Specification in a clean and elegant manner.
Did you get a chance to look at [apispec](http://apispec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)? 
 
I am finding this to be an active project with a plugin for tornado.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we are doing it in our project.  We made our own module and we are still actively developing this.  For more info: https://pypi.org/project/tornado-swirl/

```
import tornado.web
import tornado_swirl as swirl

@swirl.restapi('/item/(?P<itemid>\d+)')
class ItemHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, itemid):
        """Get Item data.

        Gets Item data from database.

        Path Parameter:
            itemid (int) -- The item id
        """
        pass

@swirl.schema
class User(object):
    """This is the user class

    Your usual long description.

    Properties:
        name (string) -- required.  Name of user
        age (int) -- Age of user

    """
    pass

def make_app():
    return swirl.Application(swirl.api_routes())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```